# What do the arrows mean in these MS Access Icons?

Tags: ms-access

Icon "Shortcut to Query":

[image: ShortcuttoQuery]

I'm responsible for a database which I did not design nor upload data to.  In this MS Access database, there are icons with an arrow pointing NE on both the tables and the queries (sample image on top of body).

When I check properties, it reads "Shortcut to table: whatever the table name is" and "Shortcut to query: whatever the query name is".

As far as I can tell, **based on the size of the db (1.5GB), these are NOT linked tables.**  Also based on the fact that the arrows aren't pointing directly to the right.

I can not recall coming across these arrows in my travels in MS Access. Once I'm able to know what they designate, I can understand what I need to do next or rather how to handle them.

My questions: what exactly do they mean functionally? What attributes do they indicate of the table outside of being a shortcut?  What is a shortcut to table/query if it isn't a linked object? I have not been able to find an answer anywhere. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe it's the image quality, but I can't see an arrow there...

Comment: I think the arrows indicate the access objects in the navigation pane (tables, queries, forms etc) have been sorted into custom groups.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you make "custom" group for the nav pain, then ALL icons will have a curved arrow on the lower left.

eg like this:

[image]

there are "more" types of icons, but the above is most

Now, if this is NOT a custom group, then the lower left curved arrow will not exist.

but if the top does NOT have a arrow then the table is local

so the top right arrow = IS A LINKED EXTERNAL table.

like this:

[image]

So in above, most are local, but one access table has a -> (right arrow), so it is a access table, but resides in ANOTHER database file.

The odbc ones of course are linked, so they have that right arrow.

So, the bottom curl arrow in the first screen shot JUST means this is a custom navigation group.

And top right arrow means the data source is EXTERNAL to access.

For specific types (Excel, or Access or SharePoint, dbBase), then you see a specific icon.

For general ODBC sources (say Oracle, or SQL server, or MySQL - you see the globe which is odbc).

there is ALSO what we call web tables, and they are depreciated, but look like this:

[image]

So, in general, if there is a right arrow (upper left), then this is a linked table (a table OUTSIDE of access).

If a curl arrow lower left, then this is really a "shortcut" to a existing linked table in your database, and of course is the result of a "custom" group having been built in the nav pane.